# Is adding another clock to the status bar on iPhone possible?

Tags: ios, widget

Is it possible to make either a jailbreak app/tweak or regular app that could display two times on the status bar on iPhone? Is such a thing possible and / or that's already developed?

I have a very special friend in another country and sometimes I forget what time it is there. Having to check the time on the clock app is a pain, especially when talking on the phone. I can't imagine a simple clock could use many system resources.

Comment: This is probably the best idea I have heard for a while. +1

Comment: Now tell me, close voters: why is this off-topic? Or are you indenting to close this just because it involves jailbreaking? That's not fair...

Comment: I don't see the problem with jailbreaking, as it is legal now, I can careless about breaking a warranty from apple, I can fix my own stuff, I only asked jailbreak, because deep inside me I know apple won't allow it with its strict guidelines. Thanks for the comments guys.

Comment: An "Is it possible" question really isn't a good question for SO.

Comment: You guys here in SO are useless, whether it says possible or not! it is a programming question regardless, sorry If I didnt major in English, but we dont all come from the US.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to make either a jailbreak app/tweak or regular app that could display two times on the status bar on iPhone?

Definitely, most likely using MobileSubstrate. What I can imagine as a solution is roughly:

1. You hook into one of SpringBoard's initialization methods.
2. You create an `UILabel` and add it to the status bar as a subview using the `addSubview:` method.
3. You spawn a timer (use `NSTimer`, Grand Central Dispatch or whatever suits you) to update the text of the label every minute or so. You can use `NSDate` and perhaps `NSLocale` (I don't have the docs in front of me right now) to find out the local time of another country.

Comment: Great Start!! I am gonna get started then. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is is why Apple hasn't already done this. They have way to many icons that can appear up at once. Adding another time would take away precious space for these other icons. When I max out the bar it bumps other icons off, like right now I have music playing but the "Play Button" Icon got bumped off by the "Navigator" Icon.

Check out this site, it shows you most of the icons if they haven't added any more in the iOS 6.

https://sites.google.com/site/appleclubfhs/support/advice-and-articles/understanding-ios-menu-symbols

Your going to have to go with jailbreaking probably or hard programming, because the status bar is basically apart of the iPhone screen.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks Seth yes indeed it can get crowded up there. I will try to develop it, all I need is hour, 2 digits. Thanks again for knowing how to read a question, as most SO users, need a well written essay to understand.

Comment: Ha, I like your comment above: "You guys here in SO are useless, whether it says possible or not! it is a programming question regardless, sorry If I didnt major in English, but we dont all come from the US." Tell 'em like it is!

Comment: I think it would have been cool if Apple would have made an option for iPhone 5 owners, where you could extend the status bar to double its width since the screen is taller. That could allow for two times. I don't know if that is an idea that you could work from to program yourself, I think that would work good. Don't forget the "AM" and "PM" Takes up a good amount of space to.